# How to block email without subjectline at all?

Tags: postfix

How to block user sending email for example from Thunderbird without subject (it doesn't add line "Subject: " if user do not add subject) via header checks?

This one blocks empty subject if there is a line with "subject"

```
/^subject: *$/   REJECT  Please add subject to your mail.
```

But if there is no "subject" line, it is not working...

Comment: The accepted answer to https://serverfault.com/questions/842344/blocking-empty-subject-line-emails-from-being-sent-or-received suggests to use SpamAssassin

Comment: I have set it in spamassasin, but it doesn't rejects, just put and spam, user do not receive any notification...

Comment: Did you read the whole answer to the linked question, especially the sentence "If you need to REJECT mails without Subject header, not just flag and/or quietly remove the mail, you can make SpamAssasin reject mail based on score by using it as a proxy-filter for Postfix." with a link in it?

Comment: Yes, but somehow didn't manage to set it right maybe..

Comment: Then you could write a question that contains details of your setup and references to  the related question and documentation and ask for help.